# If I intend to do automated tests in a project e.g. Cucumber, are unit tests needed e.g. JUnit?

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests

It seems to me it's doing the same job twice, one with mocks and the other without them. Could anyone explain why it's right or wrong?

Comment: Related: [How to use unit tests when using BDD?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/274562/118878).

Answer (score 3):

The point of doing T**D**D and B**D**D is to use tests to

## drive

the **design** of the code.  This is what unit tests are for and they should mock and stub out dependencies so they can just focus on the code under test.

Once they pass (i.e. code is developed) then you need tests to see if the code works with the other modules and services and dependencies - integrated testing.

You may also want to have a third level of testing in the UI so that the user experience is good.

You may or may not be able to share some of the valicdation code but in reality, in many cases, especially the UI you may need to duplicate the validations.

At the end of  the day the true determinant is how much value you place on the value of tests in terms of the customers.

The order should be:

```
UI tests that fail (BDD)
        \|/
Unit tests that fail (TDD)
        \|/
Write application code
        \|/
Unit tests that pass (TDD)
        \|/
 UI tests that pass (BDD)
```

[image]

Comment: I've been in projects with code developed before the testing (manual, then automated). In this case, unit testing were still needed?

Comment: They should have been created.  The question now comes up - will this code be changed? and if it is changed, will it break functionality.  If it breaks functionality, how will we know that? By poking the final result through the UI?  Code without unit tests is also code that doesn't get refactored (same scare of breaking it).  Code that doesn't get refactored (but does get changed anyway) is code that rots in the most nasty fashion.

Comment: In one of my past experiences as a developer, I didn't do any unit tests in a specific project. Software was entirely tested using Selenium and Protractor, but it was possible because every feature was linked to UI.

Comment: In that case your protractor tests (protractor) were probably your unit tests.  Unit tests that are UI tests are a bit of a headspin on the traditional 'unit tests are backend only' but in today's environment and UI code they can indeed by 'UI' Unit tests.

Comment: btw, lack of tests or crappy tests (like true == true) are very common and may indeed dominate the industry.  I am certainly pushing ideal and best states.  I like to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons which I can think of for why we still need both test types:

- In real life Unit tests do not cover 100% of code. The code has to be designed in a [special way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) to maximize its testability with unit tests.
- Your code will likely use a lot of third party libraries which might produce different erroneous outcome that is impossible to predict
- Quite often (especially the systems with user interface) use generated code sources which are not covered with unit tests
- Your components might work as you expect each in particular but the business goal might still not be addressed when they get integrated
- Unit tests are usually written by devs while integration tests are usually written by QAs. Hence providing an alternative view on expected results which is always useful.
- Sometimes it is cheaper to use the real system rather than to design a valid mock that would reflect all relevant behaviors of the resource.

Comment: Your last bullet point is your only option for existing applications whose code was not written for unit or integration testing. If the application is a giant ball of spaghetti code, then automated UI tests is really your only option. They execute slower than unit and integration tests, but it is better than nothing.